# Next.JS shallow:true route refresh the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, url-routing

I'm trying to achieve this behaviour in my Next app: when a news card is clicked, a modal with the card information opens and also the url is updated to be able to share the item url and get the info from the id `page.com\?id={item.id}`

I want to avoid refresh the state because I want that the user can close the modal an continue scrolling without lose the position. The problem is that when we click over a card, the NewsGrid component it's initializing the news from scratch. I'm using the shallow:true argument but it's not working:

````
  const { palette } = useTheme();
  const { user, profile, session } = useUser();
  const supabase = useSupabaseClient();
  const rssClass = new RSSClass();
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [openedArticle, setOpenedArticle] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchArticles = async () => {
      const articles = await rssClass.getArticles(supabase);
      setArticles(articles);
    };
    fetchArticles();
  }, []);

  const loadMoreArticles = async () => {
    if (loading) return;

    setLoading(true);
    const newPage = page + 1;
    const newArticles = await rssClass.getArticles(supabase, newPage);

    if (newArticles.length === 0) {
      setHasMore(false);
    } else {
      setArticles((prevArticles) => [...prevArticles, ...newArticles]);
      setPage(newPage);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const loadingMore = useScrollPagination(loadMoreArticles);

  const handleCardClick = (item) => {
    setOpenedArticle(item);
    router.push(`/?id=${item.id}`, undefined, { shallow: true });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const { id } = router.query;
    if (id) {
      const foundArticle = articles.find((article) => article.id === id);
      if (foundArticle) {
        setOpenedArticle(foundArticle);
      }
    }
  }, [router.query, articles]);

  if (!user) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setOpenedArticle(null);
    router.push("/", undefined, { shallow: true });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>dailyJazz</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
      </Head>
      <main>
        {openedArticle && (
          <Modal
            visible
            onClose={handleCloseModal}
            width="90%"
            maxHeight="90vh">
            <Modal.Content>
              <h2>{openedArticle.title}</h2>
              <p>{openedArticle.description}</p>
              <Button
                onClick={() => window.open(openedArticle.link, "_blank")}
                auto
                ghost
                iconRight={<ExternalLink />}>
                Read more
              </Button>
              <Spacer y={1} />
              <Button auto ghost iconRight={<X />} onClick={handleCloseModal}>
                Close
              </Button>
            </Modal.Content>
          </Modal>
        )}
        <NewsGridContainer gap={2} justify="center">
          {articles.map((item, index) => (
            <Grid
              xs={24}
              sm={12}
              md={12}
              lg={8}
              xl={6}
              key={item.id}
              style={{
                maxWidth: "80vw",
              }}>
              <div onClick={() => handleCardClick(item)}>
                <NewsCard accents_1={palette.accents_1} item={item} />
              </div>
            </Grid>
          ))}
          {loadingMore && (
            <div
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100px",
                textAlign: "center",
              }}>
              Loading more articles...
            </div>
          )}
          <ScrollToTopButton />
        </NewsGridContainer>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}```
````

Comment: When a news card is clicked, the NewsGrid component is reinitializing and fetching the articles from scratch. One possible solution is to move the articles state and the fetchArticles function to a higher-level component so that it's only fetched once and passed down to the NewsGrid component as a prop.